# Reactour not able to input on the focused component

Tags: reactjs, input, autofocus

When one of my components is in focused and it has an input field I am not able to type into it.
[image]

Comment: Can you show your code for the related component?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here in this [issue](https://github.com/elrumordelaluz/reactour/issues/209#issuecomment-640990477)

Just use `disableFocusLock` set as `true` to `Tour` and it fixes the problem.

The Tour component now looks like this for me.

```
      <Tour
        disableFocusLock={true}
        onRequestClose={() => setTourOpen(false)}
        steps={tourConfig}
        isOpen={isTourOpen}
        rounded={5}
        accentColor={"#6736DD"}
      />
```